# Show modal after successful http request

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

This is some of the most ugly code I've ever written. Please forgive me!

I want to perform a http request using Axios and then show a modal telling the user that an email has been sent.

Currently I'm using JQuery to click a hidden button which is causing the modal to show. I'm well aware the following isn't ideal but it's the only way I could get it working.

My template

```
<template>
  <div id="create-event">
    ...

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Event created</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">A mail with instructions on how to proceed has been sent to {{email}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button style="visibility: hidden" id="show-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></button>

  </div>
</template>
```

My JavaScript

```
<script>
...
import $ from 'jquery'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
    ...
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      $('#show-modal').click()
    },
    submit(e) {
      ...
      axios
        .post(url, data)
        .then(response => {
          loading.unload()
          this.showModal()
          console.log(response.data)
          this.response = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          loading.unload()
          console.log(error)
          this.errors.push(error.response.data.error)
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Please help me make this less ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
showModal() {
  $('#exampleModal').modal({
    show: true
  })
},
```

Comment: TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default(...)(...).modal is not a function
    at Proxy.showModal (CreateEvent.vue?8052:79)
    at eval (CreateEvent.vue?8052:117)

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I actually tried to delete the questions since I'm getting the impression that my approach is wrong.

Comment: I had two versions of jQuery added which was why this didn't work. But otherwise this would have been the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

at first your modal could have a v-if like:

```html
<div v-if="showModal" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Event created</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">A mail with instructions on how to proceed has been sent to {{email}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

inside your data you need a state

```js
data() {
    return {
    showModal: false
    }
  },
```

and then toggle the showModal to true if the request was successfully

```js
submit(e) {
      ...
      axios
        .post(url, data)
        .then(response => {
          loading.unload()
          this.showModal = true // <------
          console.log(response.data)
          this.response = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          loading.unload()
          console.log(error)
          this.errors.push(error.response.data.error)
        })
    }
```

thats all. the closing modal should be understandable as well now

an example of this can be found here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-vaughan-d4i7r?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: My modal isn't shown by default. Which is why I'm jumping through all these hoops. Obviously it's because of some of the bootstrap css classes but I'm not sure what to apply (or remove) to make it show without the data-toggle and data-target stuff.

Comment: @user672009 can you make a codesandbox? anyway... your modal of course shouldn't be shown initially. it should only be shown when a condition is true, like in your case when the axios is responding with a success. the v-if is doing that exactly. just try to make your modal work without a condition and then apply the v-if afterwards

Comment: i just made you a example of the behavior.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-vaughan-d4i7r?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: It should be showing if I just did v-if="true" but it doesn't and that's the problem

Comment: @user672009 the problem is somewhere else then... make the modal work first

Comment: All of that is not the problem, sorry :-) I know how v-if and such works. It's a bootstrap problem. My model should just show as is. But it only shows if I click the button.

Comment: to find out what happends when you click the button you can add a breakpoint to it. then you can see whats happening behind the curtain to make this steps manually. 
or you do a workaround and add a `yourButton.click()` to click the button automatically once the data is fetched

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I'd just like to show my modal without clicking the button.

Comment: try this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#modaloptions

but instead with { show: true } when axios responded